# How do I send mail with both plain text as well as HTML text so that each mail reader can choose the format appropriate for it?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

From http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#sendmpa:

> You'll want to send a MIME multipart/alternative message. You
>   construct such a message essentially the same way you construct a
>   multipart/mixed message, using a MimeMultipart object constructed
>   using new MimeMultipart("alternative"). You then insert the text/plain
>   body part as the first part in the multpart and insert the text/html
>   body part as the second part in the multipart. You'll need to
>   construct the plain and html parts yourself to have appropriate
>   content. See RFC2046 for details of the structure of such a message.

Can someone show me some sample code for this?

Answer (score 70):

This is a part of my own code:

```
final Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderAddress, senderDisplayName));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        new InternetAddress(m.getRecipient(), m.getRecipientDisplayName()));
msg.setSubject(m.getSubject());
// Unformatted text version
final MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setContent(m.getText(), "text/plain"); 
// HTML version
final MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(m.getHtml(), "text/html");
// Create the Multipart.  Add BodyParts to it.
final Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
// Set Multipart as the message's content
msg.setContent(mp);
LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, "Sending email {0}", m);
Transport.send(msg);
```

Where `m` is an instance of my own class.

Comment: Just note that the order in which textPart and htmlPart are added to the MultiPart instance is important. If you add them the other way around, the plain text part will be displayed to the user even when html is available (at least on gmail).