# Send email using text and html using different text

Tags: java, email

I'm using this code:

```
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setContent(bodyHtml, "text/html");
    htmlPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setText(bodyText);
    textPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
    mp.addBodyPart(textPart);
    mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
    email.setContent(mp);
```

The variables bodyText and bodyHtml have two completly different values. This is what I receive in my email client

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a113d869c2d74ca0557965663"

--001a113d869c2d74ca0557965663
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

aaa

--001a113d869c2d74ca0557965663
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<h1>aaa</h1>

--001a113d869c2d74ca0557965663--
```

The text part is just the html part with tags stripped away. But the variable bodyText contains another value. Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send mail with both plain text as well as HTML text so that each mail reader can choose the format appropriate for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756162/how-do-i-send-mail-with-both-plain-text-as-well-as-html-text-so-that-each-mail-r)